# Можно ли установить gitlab на домен отличный от .com

Tags: git, gitlab

Могу ли я запустить сервер с gitlab и связать его с доменом отличным от gitlab.example.com?

Допустим, у меня есть домен gitlab.example.ru, такой домен можно использовать или подходят только домены com зоны?

Comment: можно. что не получается?

Comment: да все норм, просто не хочу зря домен купить :D

Comment: Можно использовать и без домена, по ip.